# Flask file upload hangs on OPTIONS preflight (cross-origin post request)

Tags: flask, flask-cors

I am strugling with a strange error in Flask (APIFlask: https://apiflask.com/).
I have an app that makes cross-origin requests to sister apps. One of the functionalities is uploading data (single .zip file) with some other form fields (name etc.) to a server.

I have CORS enabled on all sister apps and can make get requests with no problems.
However, whenever I make a post request to upload the data the request hangs in mid-air.

When I look at the console of the app it says:
127.0.0.1 - - [03/May/2023 17:33:05] "OPTIONS /api/v1/islets/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -

This should be followed by the actuall POST request but it isn't. It is simply stuck in this state.
The funny part is that if I don't include the .zip file in the request it goes through, albeit, with a validation error. But if the file is included it gets simply stuck.

The file itself is not very large. Only about 7MB.

SIDE NOTE: Every app runs in its own Docker container on the same host but different ports.

My flask route looks like this:

```
CORS(islets_api) ##adds CORS to this blueprint

@islets_api.route('/', methods=["POST", "OPTIONS"])
@login_required
def add_islet():
    """
    Add islet data to db
    """
    form_data = request.form.to_dict()
    files = request.files

    if('experiment_name' not in form_data and 'description' not in form_data
        and 'sampling' not in form_data and 'protocol' not in form_data
        and 'cell_num' not in form_data):
        return {"message": "Missing input data. Check form.",  "status": "error"}, 400
    if 'islet_data' not in files:
        return {"message": "Missing islet data (.zip). Check form.",  "status": "error"}, 400

    folder_name = uuid.uuid4().hex
    folder_path = os.path.join(current_app.config.get('APP_BASE_PATH'),
                               current_app.config.get('ISLET_DATA_FOLDER'),
                               folder_name)
    os.makedirs(folder_path)
    ext = files['islet_data'].filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename = 'islet_data.' + ext
    file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
    files['islet_data'].save(file_path)

    islet = Islet(folder = folder_name, **form_data)
    db.session.add(islet)
    db.session.commit()

    return {
        'message': 'Islet uploaded successfully.',
        'status': 'success'
    }, 200
```

and my request (axios) looks like this:

```
getConfigs(){
        const api_key = member.api_key ? member.api_key : ''
        return {
            headers: {
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${api_key}`,
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
            }
        }
    }

uploadIslet(){
        const configs = this.getConfigs()
        const data = this.getFormData()
        this.startLoader()
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        axios.post(this.url, data, configs)
        .then(function(response){
            setMessage(response.data.message,
                this.alerts[response.data.status],
                this.messageContainer);
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            if(response.data.status=='success'){
                window.location.hash = 'islander-all-islets'
            }
            else{
                this.generateComponent()
            }
        }.bind(this)).catch(function(error){
            this.errorHandling(error, 'Something went wrong.')
            this.generateComponent()
        }.bind(this))
    }
```

The API key gets loaded correctly and the request doesn't fail because of authorization.
For now (development) CORS is enabled for all origins. I will change that in production.

Comment: I further tested what was going on and the results are getting even weirder. I used Postman to upload data (here, cors is not an issue) and the upload is successful only sometimes. Sometimes the request goes through and sometimes it hangs. What is even weirder is that if I don't include the file, the request always goes through, but gets a validation error. What the hell is going on?

Answer (score 2):

After losing many hours of work I arrived at the solution. The development container provided by VS Code appears to have some issues when dealing with file uploads. Specifically, when uploading files larger than 1MB or so. I could upload small files just fine (a few 10kB) but when trying to upload the actual data (~7MB) it got stuck (but not every time, which was especially confusing).
I finally tested the thing by building an image and running it in my own container and it works now.

I have no idea what exactly the issue with VS Code dev containers is but beware when using them for development.

Comment: I wasted two days with the same issue: Vue upload to flask endpoint, both on a remote workspace(ssh) with VS Code. This is so annoying as it's kind of random as you note, did you find a way to fix it?